# uncertainty about the use of multi variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got this code below

```
>>> params = {"server":"mpilgrim", "database":"master", "uid":"sa", "pwd":"secret"}
>>> params.items()
[('server', 'mpilgrim'), ('uid', 'sa'), ('database', 'master'), ('pwd', 'secret')]
```

This is the part where I'm confused.

I have `k for k` and `v`.

```
>>> [k for k, v in params.items()]  

['server', 'uid', 'database', 'pwd']

>>> [v for k, v in params.items()]
['mpilgrim', 'sa', 'master', 'secret']
```

I know it is multi variable but when I've change it to `a` for `k` and `b` for `v`, it is giving me `name 'a' is not defined` as error.

Have I missed something in my understanding of multi variable?

Comment: Where are you changing `k` to `a`? `[a for a, b in params.items()]` should work fine.

Comment: Show the exact code that is causing the error.

Comment: @chepner, I think the OP meant something like `[a for k,b in params.items()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the choice of names you use for the list comprehension, as long as you are consistent. The following work *exactly* the same:

```
[ a for a, v in params.items() ]
[ k for k, v in params.items() ]
```

---

Well, almost the same. The lists produced will be identical, but the scoping of names in a comprehension changed in Python 3. In Python 2, names used in the list comprehension are in the same scope as the calling code.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> [ a for a in range(3) ]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> a
2
```

In Python 3, comprehensions form a new scope, so names used inside the comprehension are local.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> [ a for a in range(3) ]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> a
5
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner. Actually, I'll keep it as you are answered my question.